# Conditional multiple columns in CSS

Tags: css

I have a menu containing some sub-menus, like this one

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
header {
  font-size: 20px;
}
ul {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li:nth-child(odd) {background: lightblue; }
li:nth-child(even) {background: lightyellow; }
div:not(.main) {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>menu one
  <div class="menu">
    <header>menu one header</header>
    <ul>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item two 2</li>
      <li>Item tree</li>
      <li>Item four</li>
      <li>Item five</li>
      <li>six</li>
      <li>Item 7</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div>menu two</div>
```

**I need that the 2 columns appears ONLY if there are more than 4 entries in the `.menu>ul` list.**

**Is it possible using the pure CSS?**

Comment: What columns? The two menus are 'columns'? Is nothing supposed to appear if there are less than 4 items? And I don't think you can do this as the only thing that CSS counts are children, so you can't do something like `do something to parent/other thing when amount of children of this thing is x or more` - thats what javascript is for.

Comment: Yeah you can't do this without splitting it into two `ul` elements... I'd be very curious if someone has a solution but I'm pretty sure the issue comes down to CSS simply not being good at counting or if statements...

Comment: There is a bit of a 'hack' that has been used to do this: http://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css however there appears to be some performance issues with this method.

Comment: It would be better if you simply put a class on your `ul` if it had more than 4 elements.

Comment: if you run into a wall with css capabilities (idk if this can be done with css) here's an example with jquery:  http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/336/

Comment: Do or can you use ASP, PHP or some other server side language when this menu gets created?

Comment: Yes, I can do, and finaly it was what I did... However I think is not server  side work to display a list in some columns...

Answer (score 1):

We can do with quantity query, only there is a order problem. If you compromise with that order we can use quantity query.

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  width: 40%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 2px;
}

ul li:nth-last-child(n+5),
ul li:nth-last-child(n+5)~li {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

[View on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x9rcadtf/)

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the trick described here - http://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css, which has been suggested by [@Jesse Kernaghan in the comments above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32784830/conditional-multiple-columns-in-css/32785901#comment53408841_32784830).

However, to be able to do that you need to make a couple of things hard-wired:

1. Fix the height and width of the container `ul`, and
2. Fix the height of the `li` and ensure that this width times `n` equals the height of the container `ul`. Where `n` is your magic number, in your case `4`.

This is required so that the CSS `columns` does not reflow the content and that the `li` are arranged into columns in a predictable fashion.

If your markup and use-case can work with the above two constraints, then you can use the following CSS selectors:

```
li:nth-last-child(4):first-child, 
li:nth-last-child(4):first-child ~ li {
  width: 160px;
}
```

The first selector will select the `li` which is 4<sup>th</sup> from the end and also happens to be the first, effectively selecting only the first `li` in a set of exactly four `li`s, where `4` being your magic number.

The second selector (*the general sibling combinator*) will select all the `li` that exist after the first one.

Apply a fixed width to these `li`s to give a *faux* appearance of one column.

**Example Snippet**:

```css
div.menu {
  display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;
  background: yellow; margin: 2em 1em;
}
header { font-size: 20px; }
ul {
  width: 160px; -moz-columns: 2 auto; -moz-column-fill: auto;
  -webkit-columns: 2 auto; columns: 2 auto;
  list-style: none; padding: 0; height: 8em;
}
li { height: 2em; }
li:nth-child(odd) {background: lightblue; }
li:nth-child(even) {background: lightyellow; }

li:nth-last-child(4):first-child, li:nth-last-child(4):first-child ~ li {
  width: 160px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <header>menu one</header>
  <ul>
    <li>Item one</li>
    <li>Item two 2</li>
    <li>Item tree</li>
    <li>Item four</li>
    <li>Item five</li>
    <li>six</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="menu">
  <header>menu two</header>
  <ul>
    <li>Item one</li>
    <li>Item two 2</li>
    <li>Item tree</li>
    <li>Item four</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="menu">
  <header>menu three</header>
  <ul>
    <li>Item one</li>
    <li>Item two 2</li>
    <li>Item tree</li>
    <li>Item four</li>
    <li>Item five</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Siguza: Thanks for pointing that out. I missed the `-moz-` rules. Updated.

Comment: This also creates new columns for every 4 elements outside the `ul`, so the 9th element will be in column 3, the 13th in column 4, ...

Comment: Yes @Siguza. The Op has to craft this depending on the number of `li`. In this case going beyond 8 will break it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way, tested with Chrome, FF, IE11 and Edge, though still with some fixed value, and need to be adjusted if more than 8 items.

The `li` height need to be fixed and then the negative `margin-top` will be 4 times that height to push the right items to the top.

The trick here is to have each item wider than 50% of the available width when 2 "columns" is needed, so the float's stay on its side and then push the right "column" up so it aligns with the left.

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
header {
  font-size: 20px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li:nth-child(odd) {background: lightblue; }
li:nth-child(even) {background: lightyellow; }

li { position: relative; height: 20px; }
li:nth-child(-n+4) { float: left; width: 48%; margin-right: 3%; }
li:nth-child(n+5) { float: right; width: 48%; margin-left: 3%; top: -80px }

li:nth-last-child(4):first-child, li:nth-last-child(4):first-child ~ li {
  width: 94%; margin-right: 6%
}

div:not(.main) {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>menu one
  <div class="menu">
    <header>menu one header</header>
    <ul>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item two 2</li>
      <li>Item tree</li>
      <li>Item four</li>
      <li>Item five</li>
      <li>six</li>
      <li>Item 7</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div>menu two
  <div class="menu">
    <header>menu two header</header>
    <ul>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item two 2</li>
      <li>Item tree</li>
      <li>Item four</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update** Here is another way, with flex.

Based on the `li` height and the `ul` height `n` items will fit each column.

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
header {
  font-size: 20px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100px;
}

li {
  height: 22px;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {background: lightblue; }
li:nth-child(even) {background: lightyellow; }

div:not(.main) {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>menu one
  <div class="menu">
    <header>menu one header</header>
    <ul>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item two 2</li>
      <li>Item tree</li>
      <li>Item four</li>
      <li>Item five</li>
      <li>six</li>
      <li>Item 7</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div>menu two
  <div class="menu">
    <header>menu two header</header>
    <ul>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item two 2</li>
      <li>Item tree</li>
      <li>Item four</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div>menu three
  <div class="menu">
    <header>menu three header</header>
    <ul>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item two 2</li>
      <li>Item tree</li>
      <li>Item four</li>
      <li>Item five</li>
      <li>Item six</li>
      <li>Item seven</li>
      <li>Item eight</li>
      <li>Item nine</li>
      <li>Item ten</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This stashes all elements > 4 in column two though, making a menu with 12 entries (for example) look rather unbalanced.

Comment: @Siguza Yes it does, and if more than 8 items it need to be adjusted based on if there should be more items per column or more columns, but the solution shows a way how to do.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately flex is not compatible with IE9, that we have to support... so I can't use it (

Comment: OK, but can you use the above answer (it's not flex)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there would be a "clean" way (not relying on any hard-coded numbers), but of course there's a catch...

You could use just make the `ul` always two columns, and instead use [`column-span: all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-span) to make all `li` elements span across all columns, and "undo" that by making all `li` elements, if there are more than four (`nth-last-child(n + 5)`), *not* span across all columns.
**Buuut... [Firefox doesn't support this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=616436)** (at the time of writing).

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  background: yellow;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
header {
  font-size: 20px;
}
ul {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li:nth-child(odd) {background: lightblue; }
li:nth-child(even) {background: lightyellow; }
div:not(.main) {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
li {
  -webkit-column-span: all;
  column-span: all;
}
li:nth-last-child(n + 5), li:nth-last-child(n + 5) ~ li {
  -webkit-column-span: none;
  column-span: none;
}
```

```html
<div>menu one
  <div class="menu">
    <header>menu one header</header>
    <ul>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item two 2</li>
      <li>Item t(h)ree</li>
      <li>Item four</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div><div>menu two
  <div class="menu">
    <header>menu two header</header>
    <ul>
      <li>Item one</li>
      <li>Item two 2</li>
      <li>Item t(h)ree</li>
      <li>Item four</li>
      <li>Item five</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this will some day be useful for future readers though.

There might also be a way to do this with a wrapping, two-column flexbox, but my attempts at that failed.

Answer (score 0):

I use this trick here to "help" the CSS when to break and to how many columns, by allowing it to know how many children there are.

Just with CSS this isn't possible, because CSS has no knowledge of children count of a an element, so it cannot decide what should the style be upwards in the tree.

But, with a minimal javascript code which only sets an **smart** attribute on the parent with the numbers of children in this manner: "1 2 3 4 ..." then this gives a developer full access to style a container depending on how many children it has.

#### For example, the below code breaks into 2 columns if more than 6 children exist:

```css
.list > * {
  background: lightyellow;
  border-bottom: thin dotted;
  break-inside: avoid;
  
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

/* CSS decides to how many columns to break, depending on nodes count */
.list[data-count*=' 6'] {
    columns: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="list" data-count="1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10">
  <div>item 1</div>
  <div>item 2</div>
  <div>item 3</div>
  <div>item 4</div>
  <div>item 5</div>
  <div>item 6</div>
  <div>item 7</div>
  <div>item 8</div>
  <div>item item which is very long and needs trimming is quite common</div>
  <div>item 10</div>
</div>
```